# Mixed factorial analysis in R

Tags: r, anova, spss

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

Here the first column is a factor with 2 levels (0 and 1) that represents whether a person played 2d game first or 3d game first (basically order of play). The last 2 columns are continuous variables represting score in 2d and 3d games. I want to answer the question that whether the score in 2d game is better than the 3d game and if depends on the order in which they are played. How do I do this analysis in R (or SPSS)? Please help!

Comment: Does each row correspond to one player, with number of rows = number of players? And what do the prior and post columns represent?

Comment: yes, each row is one player. you can ignore prior and post for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, e.g.

- A multilevel regression predicting the game score from the game variable (2d vs 3d), order, and their interaction, including a random intercept of participant. You can do this in R using the lmer or lme function or in SPSS using the Mixed procedure. For that, you need to reorganize your data into long format so that 2dscore and 3dscore points are in the same variable column, and then you create an additional variable column with values 2d vs 3d, showing which scores came from 2d game and which from 3d game.
- You can also use single-level model with some feature that controls for dependence in your observations (i.e. the fact that you have 2 observations from each participant), such as Generalized estimating equations (GEE). I'm not so familiar with these models, but they can be run in R using for instance geepack package and in SPSS using the Generalized estimating equations menu. For these you also need to rearrange your data into long format.
- You can also probably use repeated-measures/mixed ANOVA with order as between-participant and score (2d vs 3d) as the within-person factor. If you do this in SPSS (via ANOVA...repeated measures) you can keep your data in its current format. In R, you can use for instance rstatix package, for that you again need to reorganize your data into long format as explained before.

Whichever modeling approach you choose, the interaction effect between the game type (2d vs 3d) and order seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I used ANCOVA :D